# Python. Множества и словари

Tags: python, словари, dict, множества, set

Имеется следующая задача:

> Предположим, что нам нужно анализировать результаты матчей "команда
> против команды" по некоторому виду спорта. Для простоты будем считать,
> что "ничья" в этом виде спорта не предусмотрена и каждый матч
> описывается парой (кортежем) строк, где первая именует победителя, а
> вторая проигравшего. И сами с собой команды пусть тоже не играют :)
>
> Вам предстоит реализовать функцию wins_by_team(), которая должна
> принимать перечень (iterable) матчей в качестве единственного
> аргумента и возвращать словарь, ключами которого выступали бы имена
> команд, а значениями множества названий команд которых данная
> команда-ключ обыграла хотя бы раз.

Применение функции должно давать следующий результат:

```
>>> from solution import wins_by_team
>>> wins_by_team([])
{}
>>> wins_by_team([("A", "B")])
{'A': {'B'}}
>>> wins_by_team([("A", "B"), ("B", "A")])
{'A': {'B'}, 'B': {'A'}}
>>> wins_by_team(
...     [("A", "B"), ("B", "C"), ("A", "C")]
... ) == {'A': {'B', 'C'}, 'B': {'C'}}
...
True
>>>
```

В моем коде происходит ошибка при добавлении элемента в множество:

```
def wins_by_team(team_list):
    result = {}
    for el in team_list:
        if el[0] in result.keys():
            old_key = result[el[0]]
            result[el[0]] = old_key.add(el[1])
        else:
            result[el[0]] = {el[1]}
    return result
```

В результате, следующий вывод:

```
{'A': {'B'}}
{'A': {'B'}, 'B': {'A'}}
{'B'}
None
{'A': None, 'B': {'C'}}
```

Почему при добавлении элемента в множество возникает None? Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: `result[el[0]].add(el[1])`. Сейчас вы сначала копируете множество, потом добавляете в него элемент, а потом присваиваете вместо множества результат метода set.add (который собственно возвращает None).

Answer (score 1):

В стандартной библиотеке Питона прослеживается следующее правило: если метод меняет свой объект (или аргумент), он возвращает `None`. И наоборот, если метод что-то возвращает, он не меняет свой объект (или аргумент).

Или вычисляется новое значение, или производится побочный эффект.

Метод `set.add` меняет множество для которого он вызван - производит побочный эффект. Чтобы это подчеркнуть, он возвращает `None`. Кажется что это не удобно, требует больше кода. Но в этом есть глубокий смысл, когда вы читаете код. Возвращая `None` автор метода заставляет вас не использовать метод внутри выражения. А раз так при чтении вызова вы сразу видите что он вызван ради побочного эффекта.

Поправить ваш код не сложно:

```
def wins_by_team(team_list):
    result = {}
    for el in team_list:
        if el[0] in result.keys():
            result[el[0]].add(el[1])
        else:
            result[el[0]] = {el[1]}
    return result
```

Можно упростить его с помощью [dict.setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
def wins_by_team(team_list):
    result = {}
    for el in team_list:
        # Ой-ой! Этот метод нарушает правило, которое я так рекламировал.
        # Он и меняет словарь и возвращает значение ключа. Мда!
        result.setdefault(el[0], set()).add(el[1])
    return result
```

Я бы ещё цикл поправил:

```
def wins_by_team(team_list):
    result = {}
    for w, l in team_list:
        result.setdefault(w, set()).add(l)
    return result
```

Ещё вариант с [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict). Я его меньше люблю, но он имеет право на существование:

```
import collections


def wins_by_team(team_list):
    result = collections.defaultdict(set)
    for w, l in team_list:
        result[w].add(l)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def wins_by_team(games):
    winners = {team for team, _ in games}
    return {
        team: {looser for winner, looser in games if winner == team}
        for team in winners
    }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]